# Error with `adb sideload`when trying to install Android 12 in recovery mode

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, side-loading, android-12

According to [Google's "Get Android 12" guide](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/get),

> The easiest way to get Android 12 Beta on a Google Pixel device is to enroll your device in the Android Beta for Pixel program.

but also

> Alternatively, you can flash or manually install the latest Android 12 Beta build on your Pixel device. These approaches can be useful when you need more control over testing, such as for automated testing or regression testing.

I had previously joined the beta program to test Android 11 developer preview so for Android 12, I thought I'd try the flashy way.

I followed [this guide](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/install-android-12-developer-preview-its-lot-easier-than-you-think-0384359/) to flash the update to my Pixel 3XL. However, when I finally typed the `adb sideload` command and pressed "Enter", it gave

```
adb sideload ~/Downloads/crosshatch-spb4.210715.011-factory-cbdbee68.zip 
adb: sideload connection failed: no devices/emulators found
adb: trying pre-KitKat sideload method...
adb: pre-KitKat sideload connection failed: no devices/emulators found
```

and `adb devices` doesn't find any devices connected, although my Pixel 3XL is indeed connected through the cable, and is in recovery mode, up to step 6 of the guide. How do I get pass the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I had not completed the final part of step 6 of the guide, namely, after selecting "Apply update from ADB" in Recovery Mode, I had not pressed the power button one more time.

Once I noticed that and pressed the power button, I suppose that that got my device ready for flashing from my Mac, and `adb devices` started showing the device, and `adb sideload` was ok.